# Prove that $f(x) - f(x^{*}) \geq \frac{m}{2} \| x - x^{*} \|^{2}$.

Tags: analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Suppose $MI \succeq \nabla^{2}f(x) \succeq mI $ for $ M > m > 0$ and that $ \nabla f(x^{*}) = 0 $.

Prove that $f(x) - f(x^{*}) \geq \frac{m}{2} \| x - x^{*} \|^{2}$.

Since $ \nabla f(x^{*}) = 0 $, we know that $f(x) \geq f(x^{*})$. Also the Hessian is positive semi-definite and $f$ is convex.

Also, this is a property of strongly convex functions?

I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fundamental theorem of calculus and partial integration to get
$$
f(x+v)=f(x)+\int_0^1f'(x+tv)[v]\,dt=f(x)+f'(x)[v]+\int_0^1(1-t)f''(x+tv)[v,v]\,dt
$$
and apply the the restrictions on the spectrum of the Hessian.

Comment: I am struggling using your idea on this lil problem of mine. Could you please take a look at it and help me with the solution? Suppose that $x^*$ is an optimal solution to the following least squares problem:
$$ \min_{x\in R^n} f(x): = \frac{1}{2} \| Ax - b \|_2^2.$$ 
Clearly, we have $f(x) \ge f(x^*) \ \forall x \in R^n.$ Prove that the difference $[f(x) - f(x^*)]$ between the objective function values of any feasible solution and optimal solution is the following: 
$$ f(x) - f(x^*) = \frac{1}{2} \| Ax - Ax^*\|^2_2, \ \forall \ x \in R^n.$$

Comment: This can be done with just binomial expansion of the norm square, $Ax+b=A(x-x^*)+(Ax^*+b)$, and using that $A^T(Ax^*+b)=0$ from the necessary gradient condition.